# (Python) Is there an easier way to assign elements from a list to elements in another list?

Tags: python

Say I have n number of workers in a list, each with a different arbitrary skill level, e.g:

```
workers = [10, 50, 20, 30, 100, 150]
```

I need to assign these workers to one of two different types of jobs. One type of job requires that workers be below or equal to a certain skill level (with the skill levels given as an element of that list) e.g:

```
job_one = [20, 5, 100, 25]
```

While another job requires that workers be higher than or equal to a certain skill level: e.g.:

```
job_two = [30, 20, 25, 60]
```

I need to write a program that maximizes the number of workers assigned to a job, and finds that value. I've tried writing this by sorting (.sort()) all lists and then using for loops for each list to assign each job to a worker. Then, the job is removed (.remove()).

However, this method becomes extremely inefficient when dealing with larger sets, and as I only need the maximum number of jobs taken up I believe there might be a simpler method. Is this the case? Help is much appreciated.

Expected Output:

```
jobs_assigned = 6
```

Comment: I might be daft, but I don't understand how a job can have more than one skill level. Are these subtasks within the job, and each subtask gets a worker assigned?

Comment: Sounds like a bipartite graph matching problem to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching

Comment: How are these limits provided? What's the main goal here - "maximized the number of workers assigned to a job" - do you mean spreads it evenly across both jobs? Do you have any examples of these limits? In your case - the only jobs that needs to be distributed are those that are within the overlapping interval between the two limits; count the number of jobs under, the number of jobs over, then divide the remaining jobs according to those offsets?

Comment: It is better if you post your expected output for the examples you have given.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I meant to assign a worker to one of the two different types of jobs. Also, the only thing that makes job_one and job_two different is that for one, there is a maximum cap on skill level and for the other, a minimum cap.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code-writing service

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```py
jobs_assigned=len(job_one)+len(job_two)-len([i for i in job_one if i<min(workers)])+len([i for i in job_two if i>max(workers)])
```

This assumes that a worker can be assigned with more than one job, inferred from expected output provided in question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your goal:

```
workers_skill = {
    "Philip Ross": 100,
    "Andrew Smith": 70,
    "Jen Sam": 95,
}

skill_required = {
    "Work 1": 90,
    "Work 2": 100,
    "Work3": 30
}

def assign_work(job):
    squad = []
    print(f"Squad for the {job} - skill {skill_required[job]}")
    print("\n")
    print("Actual workers_skill:")
    for w in workers_skill:
        print(w, workers_skill[w])
        if workers_skill[w] >= skill_required[job]:
            squad.append(w)
    print()
    print("Result:")
    print(f"Job {job}(minimum skill:{skill_required[job]})")
    for w in squad:
        print("-" + w)

assign_work("Work 1")
```

output:

Squad for the Work 1 - skill 90

```
Actual workers_skill:
Philip Ross 100
Andrew Smith 70
Jen Sam 95

Result:
Job Work 1(minimum skill:90)
-Philip Ross
-Jen Sam
```